# MongoDB is aggregation discourage over simple query

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

We are running a MongoDB instance for some of our price data, and I would like to find the most recent price update for each product that I have in the database.

Coming from a SQL background my initial thought was that to create an query with a subquery, where the subquery is a group by query. In the subquery price updates are grouped by the product and then one can find the most recent update for each price update.

I talked to a colleague about this approach and he claimed that in the official training material from MongoDB it is said that one should prefer simple queries over aggregated ones. i.e. he would run a query for each product and then find the most recent price update by ordering them by the update date. So that the number of queries will be linear in comparison to the number of products.

I do agree that it is simpler to write such a query, instead of an aggregated one, but I would have thought that performance wise it would have been faster to go through the collection once and find the queries i.e. the number of queries will be constant in comparison to the number of products.

He claims also that mongodb also will be able to better do optimization when running simple queries when running in a cluster.

Anybody know if that is the case?

I tried to search on the internet and I cannot find such a claim that one should prefer simple queries over aggregated ones.

Another colleague of mine was also thinking that it may be the case that since MongoDB are a new technology, then maybe aggregation queries have not been optimized for clustered MongoDB instances.

Anybody who can shed some light on these matters?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information on the aggregation pipeline on a sharded MongoDb implementation

[Aggregation Pipeline and Sharded Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/aggregation-pipeline-sharded-collections/)

Assuming you have the right indexes in place on your collections, you shouldn't have any problems using MongoDB aggregation.